# How can an external JavaScript access html elements output by xmlhttprequest?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Xmlhttprequest
I'm returning a html div element from a php file to another php file using xmlhttprequest ajax

I'm outputting the div xhr.responseText with innerhtml. Example

`document.querySelector('div.users').innerHtml = xhr.responseText;`

Which is working fine.

The problem is that the response gotten is not accessible by an external JavaScript

Example. The response is like this.
`<div class="me">hello world</div>`

When I use an external JavaScript to get the the elements.
Nothing works.
Example

```
document.querySelector('.me').addEventListener("click", () =>{console.log("hi");});
```

Nothing happens when the element is clicked.

Any solution please?

Comment: You might need to write event listener inside the function where you are appending inner html.

Comment: How do i do it?